# Attaching pulumi_azure.compute.LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSet instance to pulumi_azure.network.ApplicationGateway's backend pool

Tags: python, pulumi

I'm trying to figure out how to connect `pulumi_azure.compute.LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSet` instance to a backend pool of `pulumi_azure.network.ApplicationGateway` using Python.

Looking at documentation of `pulumi_azure.compute.LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSet`
( https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure/compute/linuxvirtualmachinescaleset )
it seems that the chain of necessary links would be:

- step 1 - create `LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterfaceIpConfiguration` instance with appropriate `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPoolIds` set
- step 2 - create `LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterface` instance with network interface ip configuration from step 1
- step 3 - create `LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSet` with network_interface from step 2

However while this is what documentation says
`LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterfaceIpConfiguration`
and
`LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterface`
are not defined in `pulumi_azure.compute` (`version 3.17.0`, newest as of this writing).

Looking at code samples in both documentation and pulumi_azure.compute's source code, the only way to set network_interfaces argument to `LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSet` is to provide it with a list of dictionaries, e.g.

```
network_interfaces=[{
    "name": "example",
    "primary": True,
    "ip_configurations": [{
        "name": "internal",
        "primary": True,
        "subnet_id": ....
    }],
    "network_security_group_id": ...
}],
```

So what would be the correct way to associate scaling set with application gateway's backend pool?

Answer (score 0):

After looking through source code of `pulumi_azure/compute/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.py` I realized that `LinuxVirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterfaceIpConfiguration` etc mentioned in pulumi's documentation are not classes, but plain dictionaries.

`ip_configuration` field of `network_interface` argument to scale set constructor accepts optional `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPoolIds` keyword, which can be used to associate scale set with application gateway's backend pool.